# "Это уже к вопросу комплекса его вины", - вопрос комплекса вины?

Tags: управление

> Разглядывая Моисея, воспринимая его позу, я сразу же отказалась от
>   общего мнения, что в фигуре пророка «живёт ярость и порыв разбить
>   скрижали». Впрочем, не согласна я и с Фрейдом до конца. Я не вижу
>   здесь, как пишет доктор, «презрительно-гневного взгляда». **Это уже к
>   вопросу комплекса его вины**. Перед нами фигура Пророка, и
>   Микеланджело подчёркивает его исключительность всеми возможными
>   средствами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, фраза странная. Из "вопроса комплекса" следует само собой разумеющимся приписываемый человеку "комплекс вины", а сочетание "комплекс **его вины**" (вместо "комплекс вины" *у него*) вызывает сомнение в правильности понимания автором этого понятия. Комплекс вины - *внутреннее* психологическое состояние (склонность себя винить в чём-то), а не "чья-то вина", образующая комплекс, как можно заключить из авторского текста. Если же автор хотел порассуждать о *наличии* у человека такого комплекса, можно было сказать иначе: *к вопросу об (о якобы) имевшемся у него комплексе вины.*

Comment: Саша, спасибо! ЛОшку выдаст автор.

Answer (score 1):

В основе рассуждения лежит статья Зигмунда Фрейда "Моисей Микеланджело" 1914г.

https://psychic.ru/articles/classic63.htm

**1) О комплексе вины**

...Как часто поднимался я по крутой лестнице с неброской Корсо-Кавоур к безлюдной площади, на которой затерялась заброшенная церковь, **сколько раз пытался выдержать презрительно-гневный взгляд героя!** Украдкой выскальзывал я иногда из полутьмы внутреннего помещения, **чувствуя себя частью того сброда,** на который устремлен его взгляд, сброда, который не может отстоять свои убеждения, не желая ждать и доверять, и который возликовал, лишь вновь обретя иллюзию золотого тельца.

2) В статье автор подробно рассказывает, как по-разному критиками воспринималась фигура Моисея. Многие считали, что Моисей в следующий момент разобьет скрижали в порыве гнева. **Фрейд тоже не сразу пришел к определенному мнению, но в конце статьи он считает, что Моисей усмирил свой гнев,** что порыв ярости пройден, что он осознал свою великую миссию.

...Однако он преодолел искушение: так он и останется сидеть теперь, укротив свой гнев, с выражением **боли и презрения** на лице. Он не бросит скрижали наземь, и они не разобьются о камни, ведь именно ради них и обуздал он свой праведный гнев, ради их спасения усмирил свой пламень.

3) Что касается текста, то читателю он может показаться недостаточно ясным — **о каком комплексе вины идет речь**. Может быть, надо что-то добавить. И по поводу **гнева** тоже, ведь в конечном счете (по Фрейду) он преодолел свой гнев.

Comment: Меня и падежи смущают - в разговоре о комплексе. А чей комплекс?  - думаю, дедушки Фрейда. *Вопрос комплекса...*

Comment: Ну да, его, он же свои впечатления описывает, когда ему кажется, что он не лучше "этого сброда." Может, так: Я не вижу здесь, как пишет доктор, «презрительно-гневного взгляда», который было бы трудно выдержать (это уже к вопросу о комплексе вины по Фрейду).

Comment: Всё, шлю автору. Пусть разбирается!